# How to do customisation in smartedit-Hybris?

Tags: angularjs, sap-commerce-cloud

How can we do customisation in smartedit-Hybris using the front end technologies?

Answer (score 1):

The SmartEdit architecture can be split into two blocks: the frontend and the backend. It is as follows:

- **Frontend:** The frontend consists of the smartedit and cmssmartedit extensions. These extensions are written in JavaScript using the AngularJS framework. In order to manage the build life cycle of the JavaScript-based extensions, like cleaning, building, packaging, minifying, or beautifying the code, some libraries are required that are not provided by the SAP Commerce Platform by default. SmartEdit uses the npmancillary extension to store and organize the required libraries.
- **Backend:** The backend consists of the smarteditwebservices, cmswebservices, cmssmarteditwebservices, cmsfacades,cms2, and cms2lib extensions. These extensions are built in Java using the Spring framework.

[Refer this](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/6d55d5fba206425b9acecda9f2311483.html) to Setup Up Your SmartEdit Development Environment & Example of Wiring Custom Module

source: https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/4b239c875acc4a19abd559a62eb73c91.html